# Dependency injection inconsistency in differing ViewControllers in Swinject, post Swift 3.0 update: why?

Tags: ios, swift, swinject

I am registering some `Swinject` singleton-with-a-small-s (.container) services thus:

```
defaultContainer.register( SomeService.self )
{
    _ in SomeService() 
}.inObjectScope( .container )

defaultContainer.register( AnotherService.self )
{
    responder in AnotherService(
        someService: responder.resolve( SomeService.self )!
    )
}.inObjectScope( .container )
```

Injecting them into some view controllers thus:

```
defaultContainer.registerForStoryboard( SomeViewController.self )
{
    resolvable, viewController in
    viewController.someService = resolvable.resolve( SomeService.self )
    viewController.anotherService = resolvable.resolve( AnotherService.self )!
}

defaultContainer.registerForStoryboard( AnotherViewController.self )
{
    resolvable, viewController in
    viewController.someService = resolvable.resolve( SomeService.self )
    viewController.anotherService = resolvable.resolve( AnotherService.self )!
}
```

These view controllers are then being displayed in two different ways, `SomeViewController` like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async
{
    self.performSegue( withIdentifier: "somePageSegue", sender: nil )
}
```

And `AnotherViewController` like this:

```
let anotherViewController = UIStoryboard(
    name: "Main"
    , bundle: nil
).instantiateViewController( withIdentifier: "anotherSegue" )

present( anotherViewController, animated: true, completion: nil )
```

`SomeViewController` gets its services injected, but unfortunately `AnotherViewController` does not.

This used to work prior to `Swinject`'s upgrade to Swift 3.0, but does not now. Why is this, and what needs to be changed, please?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I have neither the familiarity with `Swinject`'s underlying code base nor the time to familiarize myself unfortunately, but digging around with what is happening under the surface I have discovered the following, which is hopefully useful to anyone who might know it better than I:

**SUCCESSFUL VC DI:**

```
// once into:
private func injectDependency(to viewController: UIViewController)

// then:
defaultContainer.registerForStoryboard( SomeViewController.self )

// then many times into:
public func _resolve<Service, Factory>(name: String?, option: ServiceKeyOptionType? = nil, invoker: (Factory) -> Service) -> Service?
```

**FAILED VC DI:**

```
// repeatedly going from:
private func injectDependency(to viewController: UIViewController)

// to:
public func _resolve<Service, Factory>(name: String?, option: ServiceKeyOptionType? = nil, invoker: (Factory) -> Service) -> Service?

// and back again,
// then twice into:
public override func instantiateViewController(withIdentifier identifier: String) -> UIViewController
```

**ADDITIONAL NOTES:**

The failing VC is a UIViewController within a TabBarController, both of which are already laid out in a standard XCode storyboard.

Comment: have you setup container for SwinjectStoryboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is a bug, detailed here: https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject/issues/177. A fix is currently being worked on. I will report back once I know more.

**UPDATE**

This is apparently fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In order for `registerForStoryboard` to be invoked you need to instantiate given controller from `SwinjectStoryboard`, not just `UIStoryboard`:

```
let anotherViewController = SwinjectStoryboard.create(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "anotherSegue")

present(anotherViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks @Jakub-Vanu I'll try this out now

Comment: Unfortunately that hasn't made any difference @Jakub-Vano but thanks for suggesting it.

Comment: Is `defaultContainer` in your code `SwinjectStoryboard.defaultContainer` ?

Comment: Hi @Jakub-Vano. Yes I've got: extension SwinjectStoryboard { class func setup ( { defaultContainer.register... wherein sit all my registrations